# When text wraps within TextBlock, ActualHeight is incorrect

Tags: wpf, textblock, actualheight

I have a `TextBlock` with a `Border` around it that's inside of a `Canvas` that I'm using to animate it as part of a custom control.  The block slides in from the bottom of the screen over the top of the image.  I'm trying to use the `ActualHeight` of the `TextBlock` to determine how far to move it onto the page, but when there is so much text that it wraps to two lines, the `ActualHeight` returns the same size as though there was a single line.

TextBlock:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type contentTypes:BusinessAdText}" x:Key="BusinessAdTextTemplate">
    <Border Background="#a9a9a975"
        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=ActualWidth}">
        <TextBlock Margin="20" Text="{Binding Text}"
            TextWrapping="Wrap">
        </TextBlock>
        </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

This style is applied which has the canvas:

```
<Style TargetType="local:BusinessAd">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:BusinessAd">
                <Border Background="Transparent">

                    <Canvas ClipToBounds="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Content"                                                  
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Canvas>

                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Code behind for BusinessAd.cs has:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    _contentPart = GetTemplateChild("PART_Content") as FrameworkElement;                        
}
```

Then just using a simple DoubleAnimation I move it onto the screen:

```
if (_contentPart != null && _isLoaded)
{
    _storyboard.Stop();

    vAnimation.From = ActualHeight;
    vAnimation.To = ActualHeight - _contentPart.ActualHeight;
    //_contentPart.ActualHeight returns 46.something no matter how much text is there

    vAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Duration));

    if (_storyboard.Children.Count == 0)
    {
        _storyboard.Children.Add(vAnimation);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(vAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(vAnimation, _contentPart);                                                           
    }

    _storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `UpdateLayout()` before checking `ActualHeight`:

```
if (_contentPart != null && _isLoaded)
{
    _storyboard.Stop();
    UpdateLayout();

    vAnimation.From = ActualHeight;
    vAnimation.To = ActualHeight - _contentPart.ActualHeight;
    //_contentPart.ActualHeight returns 46.something no matter how much text is there

    vAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Duration));

    if (_storyboard.Children.Count == 0)
    {
        _storyboard.Children.Add(vAnimation);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(vAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(vAnimation, _contentPart);                                                           
    }

    _storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I ended up going about this a totally different way.  I created a TextBlock in memory and then measured it to get the height.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies to you, but for me, the textblock in `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` needs to be preceded with this:

```
myTextBlock.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
```

Before, when I had just `myTextBlock.Measure(new Size());`, it worked when there wasn't any text wrapping, but with wrapping `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` returned the dimensions of the word/letter, depending on WrapWholeWords or Wrap